# C#: Button doesn't work inside Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, webforms

I have a somewhat really random problem which I just can not understand.

My website has a page where, after selecting a value from a DropDownList, it generates a form automatically (a TextBox with a Button to confirm it).

The problem being that, the button is not doing anything. It does not seem to be connected to the method I have created which I find very weird considering I have used very similar code for another page and it worked just fine.

Here is the ASP.NET:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="PossibleItems" OnSelectedIndexChanged="PossibleItems_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="true" Value="defaultValue">Select an item</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Purpose" Text="Purpose"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Currency" Text="Currency"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="PaymentMethod" Text="Payment Method">    </asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <asp:GridView ID="ItemNamesList" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
    <asp:Label ID="ItemName" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Panel ID="AddItemForm" runat="server">
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

Here is the code:

```
    protected void PossibleItems_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Generate the form
        generateForm();
    }

    protected void generateForm()
    {
        // if the administrator wants to create a new payment method
        else if (PossibleItems.SelectedValue.Equals("PaymentMethod"))
        {
            Label pmName = new Label();
            pmName.Text = "Payment method name : ";
            TextBox pmNameTB = new TextBox();
            AddItemForm.Controls.Add(pmName);
            AddItemForm.Controls.Add(pmNameTB);
            AddItemForm.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));

            // IMPORTANT PART: THIS IS WHERE I CREATE THE BUTTON
            Button pmBTN = new Button();
            pmBTN.Text = "Create";
            pmBTN.Click += (sender1, EventArgs) => { addPaymentMethod(sender1, EventArgs); };
            AddItemForm.Controls.Add(pmBTN);
        }
    }


    protected void addPaymentMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("AddChange.aspx?id=18");
    }

}
```

I have tried removing as much fluff as possible.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Dynamically added controls and event handlers are NOT preserved across postbacks. The easiest way to solve your problem is to add your form to the .aspx with Visible="False" and show/hide it as appropriate.

Comment: >Dynamically added controls and event handlers are NOT preserved across postbacks.

What do you mean by that? It sounds weird to me considering I have added other buttons dynamically to a GridView with a OnRowDataBound trigger which work just fine. What is the difference with the buttons here?

Comment: You're adding the controls using `.Controls.Add` Is that what you're doing with the GridView too? I think not.

Comment: I am actually. This is the code for the other buttons for the GridView if you are interested: https://pastebin.com/vxhCm5Sh

Comment: Yikes, you're going to really want to rethink your design. You're writing this as if it's Windows Forms. It's not. This is Web Forms - it's better to control the visibility of controls than to add them on the fly. It's also better to declaratively set the event handlers in the ASPX markup rather than assign them on the fly.

Comment: Well thank you for your concern but this is really not helping me understanding the problem better.

Comment: In your GridView example, you're probably data-binding the grid on the initial request as well as on each postback, so your dynamic controls continue to exist. Here the SelectedIndexChanged method *isn't* getting called on every postback, so your dynamic controls disappear.

Comment: How about not generating a dynamic form but instead hide/show fields based on the selected payment type? You can do this by including runat and visible attributes.